# Shopware 6 Admin Api - Updating existing record through patch method. Not working

Tags: api, patch, shopware6, shopware6-api

shopware 6 admin api patch - why it's failing? I get error `"Only single write operations are supported"`

Following is api for `rule-condition` entity in the database, I update it with `Id`.
For same api `get method` is working!

`url`: api/rule-condition/dbb0d904c7c14860a9a94cf26b94eca6

`method`: patch

**json body**

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/data/attributes/value/email",
        "value": "test@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

**response:**

> {
> "errors": [
> {
> "code": "0",
> "status": "400",
> "title": "Bad Request",
> "detail": "Only single write operations are supported. Please send the entities one by one or use the /sync api endpoint.",
> .......

I also tried changing json body to following

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "value": {
                "email": "test@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    } }
```

Still it's not updating. Can somebody check and let me know what am i missing?

Documentation I followed:
https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTQ5-writing-entities

This website has all apis and example methods. https://swagger.docs.fos.gg/,
`rule-condition` entity can also be found there.

Btw : I used postman for testing api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an array of objects in the request body, suggesting you want to update multiple records, but the endpoint only supports updating a single record. The correct payload in your case should look like this:

```json
{
    "value": { 
        "operator": "=", 
        "email": "test@gmail.com" 
    }
}
```

Notice that `value` is a json field and not only includes a single value. The exact content and the names of the properties of `value` depend on the type of condition used and usually it also includes the operator used in the condition.

Comment: oh great! Thank you very much. I tried this earlier as well but nested json object. it wasn't updated and neither was throwing error so it wasn't clear what was the issue. Thanks for your time, much apprecited.